# Как записать предложение в словарь с первым словом как ключ?

Tags: python

Столкнулся с проблемой. Не знаю как сделать так, чтобы предложение хранящееся в переменной, допустим `a`, переписалась в другую переменную таким образом:

```
a = 'у меня есть проблема'
#переписалась вот так
b = {'первое слово до пробела':, 'все остальные слова'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
k,v = a.split(maxsplit=1)

b = {k: v}
```

---

результат:

```
In [24]: b
Out[24]: {'у': 'меня есть проблема'}
```

Comment: я понял спасибо!